# How to pass values and get response from a Runnable Thread in Android with exit function?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-intent

I implemented a login form in android, it was advised that i should use runnable thread to bring data from webservice for login authentication, as android suggests to use runnable thread for network function. I did the same but is there any function which will be called when thread will be executed, if a login is authenticated, i want that thread should return value e.g 1 and on its bases i will execute some function to do next task. I have seen many solutions like implementing a class and passing parameter, but none of them worked for my requirement. I am writing down the steps to explain my problem further.

1- I want to pass two parameters to runnable thread LoginValidation
    function. 
 2- I want to get the return value from the thread
    function, in my main thread. 
 3- I want to call some other function of my parent thread (main thread)
    after my child thread is finished, as i want to do next task in it,
    like opening the profile screen.

I used the global variable "loginResponse" in my code, but it is not helping.

I am writing my code here, i am new bie in android, please excuse.

```
try{

             new Thread(new Runnable() {

                 public void run() {
                     Looper.prepare();
        WebserviceCall wb = new WebserviceCall();
        loginResponse = wb.LoginWarden("LoginWarden");



                 }
             }).start();

            //just for testing
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg:"+loginResponse+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             if (loginResponse=="1"){
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ViolationReporter.class);

        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
             }else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username or password is not valid.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             }


        }catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: so you cant use asynctask???

Comment: how to use in this way?

Comment: SO you can use asynctask for this problems??

Comment: Normally, I would say use FutureTask on an Executor with a Thread (or Runnable), butRod is right. AsyncTask is what you are looking for. If you want result from Activity - use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: Really thanks, please post is as an answer, i will select @Rod_Algonquin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the asynctask for this problem that it has all you needed..

Comment: I got what Rod suggested.